# Selecting multiple ranges simultaneously in Excel using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to use powershell to create pie charts in excel. I can highlight ranges with .Select() or .Activate() but I can't simultaneously select two separate ranges. I need to select them simultaneously so that the pie chart has the correct labels. Can't find any guidance online so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$headers = $ws.Cells.Item(1,1).EntireRow
$headers.Activate()
$ws.Range("A3:ZZ3").Activate()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it answers your question directly, but this might help: https://learn-powershell.net/2012/12/24/powershell-and-excel-adding-a-chart-and-header-filter-to-a-report/

Comment: It's a good source for general chart syntax but unfortunately as with most charts, he includes the whole table and therefore doesn't have to create a dynamic range of non-consecutive cells.

Comment: Would a quicker fix just be to put the headers next to your pie chart so that you can select them within a single range?

Comment: I had considered it as a last result, fortunately TechSpud's solution works to select the non-consecutive ranges so I don't have to deal with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1f5ffcca-c0e4-40a0-ae6e-c43b5da76398/powershell-excel-union?forum=winserverpowershell) suggest a way to select multiple ranges. Using your code above, try this...

```
[object[]]$args1 = ($headers, $ws.Range("A3:ZZ3")) 
$union=$xl.GetType().InvokeMember("Union", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod, $null, $xl, $args1) 
$union.Select()
```

...where `$xl` is defined as `$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application`